# Can I make VLC to show English subtitles if the language is not English except when it is Russian?

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles, selection

The title says it all. Can I make VLC to show English subtitles if the language is not English except when it is Russian?

I like foreign TV series, e.g. French, German, Spanish and Portuguese (sorry, have not watched recently increasingly popular Norwegian) and I would like the English subtitles to show up automatically when the series are not British or American.

I do understand Russian. So I would not want the English subtitles to show up if the series are Russian either.

Is that too much to ask?

There is a similar thread about selecting a specific subtitle track in a specific series assuming all files are the same but the wise provider of the solution does not get past 'should'. E.g. "The VLC should if", not a solution but a guess. Please do not sparkle off with your expertise if your advice uses 'should' instead of 'would'.

The VLC should show the desired Language track if chosen in settings. In my case I disabled autoload a while ago (do not remember where) but now on reenabling, it back, nothing shows.

I am watching this French series The Bureau. It has embedded subs for the most of the series but starting from the season 4 it has 2 English and 2 subtitle tracks.

It shows neither. Since I am used to seeing the embedded ones, I am disappointed to jump up back from sofa to reach the computer and press s in the middle of the dark to enable the English subtitles which are enabled in all possible ways.

I have a large video projector screen which uses a 15m HDMI cable so the computer is not next to neither screen nor projector.

[image: VLC screenshot]

Comment: Invest in a wireless keyboard with built-in trackpad;) VLC cannot do this. You can make it show [en] subs but you can't get it to make smarter decisions than that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a preferred subtitle language, but I'm not aware of the reverse (i.e. *"do not show subtitles for <language(s)>"*). Sounds useful though, you could do a feature request here: https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=7

For laptop VLC control on the couch I got a ~€40 Logitech K400 Plus keyboard a few weeks ago, which includes said trackpad (and reportedly has 12-18 month battery life on one set... my previous cheap one did a frustrating 3 sec handshake after every 15 mins of inactivity, and still went through two batteries in weeks). If you're willing to shell out go for a more expensive one with backlight, great when watching movies in a dark environment.

You can then turn the subtitles on/off with SHIFT-V, and cycle through them with V (ALT-V for reverse cycling).

Keyboard shortcuts in VLC are remappable btw, I switched V and SHIFT-V for example because I use the toggle way more often than the cycle.

Comment: I got a K830 [actually a Win keyboard for a Mac, because that was all I could get at the time with a trackpad]. It charges over USB… so infrequently I couldn't honestly say how long it lasts. Could be anywhere from 3 to 6 months. Wasn't cheap, £80. Bought in Aug 2016, showing no signs of getting old yet. I do wish you could cycle subs in reverse, though. Lemme see what we have, EngSDHH, OK do we have just Forced…nope, French… Venezuelan… Outer Mongolian…. Martian… ffs ;)

Comment: we were watching The Hobbit trilogy the other day, and I was missing Elvish, Orcish and Dwarven subtitles :P

Comment: I like your answer but IMHO a remote keyboard is an overkill. I had a very good wireless mouse for that. It was a Microsoft mouse. A one which did not cost more than £10 but was good. And indeed it was while it lasted. For couple of years. Probably I will cash out for another one. I found reference to it when searched for the best not expensive wireless mouse on search engine. I do not know why it is called Microsoft and how one mouse can be more Microsoft than others but there it is. I concluded that Bill Gates decided to make mends and produce something good once.

Comment: @DavidsGaisevskis it's the convenience of having full control... Apart from subtitles, sometimes I miss something and want to quickly go back a few seconds, or the (live) subtitles are out of whack. With a keyboard these are very quickly fixable. There used to be TV style remote controls for PCs, however they seem to have all but disappeared. Closest I found was the Logitech Harmony system, but that's what I would consider overkill :)

Comment: If nothing else, you need the spacebar [play/pause] by your side [& rewind]. I don't have a family who can make it through a single movie or TV show without needing a long comment about the plot, the dialog, the camera work, what that extra is doing in the background, a snack, a drink, a pee, or any other excuse that requires we halt the proceedings for a minute or two, or flip back 10s to have another look. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin that's pretty much me... Wait, are you my gf? :P